# How to add a javascript file (.js file) to a c# project and call a javascript method from c# code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, c#-4.0

I have added the javascript file to the project by right clicking the project.But while calling the method inside the code, I am getting an error stating 'The requested url(method) is unavailable'. So I don't know how to proceed further. I need this for creating an IE browser add-on. Please help me.

Comment: So you want to... call a Javascript method, probably using a javascript statement, so its in javascript syntax. And this needs to be coded in c#?

Comment: I work with C# and javascript a lot, the way you are trying to mix the 2 won't work

Comment: Can't we call a javascript file from c# code using execscript()?

Answer (score 0):

Added the javascript file.
In visual studio : drag and drop the js file to the aspx and it will make a tag like

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Calling Javascript from codebehind

in codebehind

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "Showalert('test');", true);
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "importingdone", "ImportingDone();", true);
```

calls this scripts in the front

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function Showalert(name) {
            alert('Profile not parsed!!' + name);
            window.parent.parent.parent.location.reload();
        }

        function ImportingDone() {
            alert('Importing done successfull.!');
            window.parent.parent.parent.location.reload();
        }
    </script>
```

Note : first call is with parameter, second without.

If you need otherwise read the article below.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/850541/JqueryAjaxToCs

Hope it helps you

Comment: Mine is not a aspx file. It is a .cs file

Comment: Sorry understood that sinds your creating for IE.. Sorry.

Comment: Any possibility for .cs file??

Comment: Not that i'm aware. I'm only doing web. Good luke